# What flags does queryIntentActivities() take?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

What flags does [queryIntentActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) take (other than [MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY))?

I ask because I want my application to check whether my other application is installed. Because it's using Intent.ACTION_MAIN, it doesn't seem necessary to use MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY. Should I use zero as the flag, or is there something more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to check whether your other application is installed or not, you can use the method `getApplicationInfo(String packageName, int flags)` of [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class. Pass the package name you want to find and pass a 0 as second parameter.
Put this method in try-catch block and if the method throws a `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException` then your other app is not installed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java) of the `PackageManger` class in AOSP, that should help answering what are other possible flags.

`PackageManger` class has below code,

```
/** @hide */
    @IntDef(flag = true, prefix = { "GET_", "MATCH_" }, value = {
            GET_META_DATA,
            GET_RESOLVED_FILTER,
            GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES,
            MATCH_ALL,
            MATCH_DEBUG_TRIAGED_MISSING,
            MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS,
            MATCH_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED_COMPONENTS,
            MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY,
            MATCH_DIRECT_BOOT_AUTO,
            MATCH_DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE,
            MATCH_DIRECT_BOOT_UNAWARE,
            MATCH_SYSTEM_ONLY,
            MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES,
            MATCH_INSTANT,
            GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS,
            GET_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED_COMPONENTS,
            GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES,
    })
```

Here you can see the `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` Flag along with several other flags mentioned.